# Utilizar Identity em uma aplicação Asp.Net MVC 5 com Web Api e vice versa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api

Quando eu crio um projeto `Asp.Net MVC` com `Individual User Accounts` eu posso entrar na aplicação dessa maneira:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Mas eu preciso disponibilizar acesso ao login para aplicações mobile dessa forma:

```
link: http://localhost:51836/token  
header: content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
body: username=teste@gmail.com&password=123456&grant_type=password
```

Como faço para continuar fazendo login dessa forma e disponibilizar também `Web Api`(no mesmo projeto `Asp.Net MVC`) para que dispositivos móveis façam login e recebam `Token` de acesso para poderem acessar as páginas `Web Api` que eu tiver na aplicação `Asp.Net MVC`?

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria uma Action (anonima) a parte para o login do aplicativo mobile.

Então nesta action eu buscaria o usuario e então chamaria o código que você postou.

Saca ?

Cria uma Action eu um controller que possa ser acessa sem autenticar

nesta action, busca o usuario, e caso sucesso chame

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Depois disso o resto da aplicação nao precisa preocupar de onde veio ousuario